# Spherical geometry: Arbitrary point between two points

Tags: spherical-geometry

If A and B are two points on the earth, how could I find any arbitrary point between them along the shortest distance side of their great circle path?

Points are in radians
longitude = $0$ to $2\pi$
latitude = $0$ to $\pi$, $0$ being at north pole
Points are not antipodal

I desire something where I specify a range $0.0$ to $1.0$, with $0.0$ being point A and $1.0$ being point B and $0.5$ being the midpoint between them, with all other values being their corresponding points.  Thanks!

Note:  This is not homework.  I'm 41yrs old and this is for a personal project I'm working on.

Comment: Good question.  It is an embarrassment to the site that a climate has been created where users feel they have to post detailed personal disclaimers (even about subjects that *are not taught* in today's education system -- spherical geometry!) to avoid the accusation of posting homework.

Comment: Here's an idea: you first get the spherical distance of your two points, construct an equatorial arc of that length, and then rotate the arc such that the ends coincide with the original points. I don't have the time to work out the mathematics completely, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist) aviation website has the information that you were looking for. The formula presented there returns the latitude and longitude of a point that is a fraction $f$ between points A and B except when they are antipodal just as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Nice! Note that safe implementations couch any use of inverse trigonometric functions in terms of the two-argument arctangent.